# Use mutliprocessing Pool to read csv and change global arrays

Tags: csv, python-multiprocessing, pool

I prepared a serial process which reads a large csv file (step 1), creates some global arrays (step 2), and changes the elements within the global arrays based on each element of the csv file (step 3).

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

"""
Step 1
"""

file = 'filename.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=6)
df.head()

"""
Step 2
"""

r_lim = np.array([0.0, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0004, 0.0005, 0.0006, 0.0007, 0.0008, 0.0009, 0.001, 0.0011, 0.0012, 0.0013, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0016, 0.0017, 0.0018, 0.0019, 0.002])
r_vol = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
total_vol = 0.0

"""
Step 3
"""

def calc():
    global total_vol
    for i in range(len(df)):
        x = df.iloc[i, 1]
        y = df.iloc[i, 2]
        vol = df.iloc[i, 0]
        r_loc = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
        for y in range(len(r_vol)):
            r_0 = r_lim[y]
            r_1 = r_lim[y+1]
            if r_loc >= r_0 and r_loc < r_1:
                r_vol[y] += vol
                break
        total_vol += vol

calc()
print(r_vol)
print(total_vol)
```

In serial, this process works great. However, I can't set this up to work with multiprocessing using Pool.
The way I thought of doing this is:

1. Set the global variables,
2. Globally read the .csv file, by skipping the first 6 rows
3. Use Pool to run the calc() process to change the global arrays accordingly and then join everything together.

Is what I am thinking possible? Does each parallel processor need to individually read the .csv file?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to these things:

1. Share `r_lim`, `r_vol` and `total_vol` across processes so that every processes can see them. If the lengths of `r_lim` and `r_vol` are fixed, you can use [multiprocessing.Array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array). You can use [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) to store `total_vol`
2. Use a lock to protect the modification of `r_vol` and `total_vol`. If you use multiprocessing.Array and multiprocessing.Value to store them, you don't need to worry about this since they have their own locks by default.

But since your csv file is large and the content will be copied to each process, you need to take care of your memory usage. If your memory usage is exceeded, you'd better to read different parts of the file in each process.

Furthermore, it seems that the actual calculation in `calc()` is not very heavy(just calculating Euclidean distance I think?), so I'd like to recommend you to use a ThreadPool instead of a ProcessPool since it'll be much easier to share variables across threads. You can try [concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor).